# Playwright auto-scroll to bottom

Tags: playwright

I want to scroll down automatically in CRM web page I am using tool playwright.
can I get any method or line of code in playwright.

i have already written code
await page.evaluate(() => document.body.style.zoom = 0.5  );

thanks,

Comment: Please share the site and your code as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: Added an answer, please see if this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling can be done many ways.

If you have a locator you wish to bring into view use:

```
await locator.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
```

This is ideal if you just want to do some action on a locator, and is the cleanest way. It will scroll until the locator is in view, taking some `options` where needed.

If its a specific page, you can use:

```
await mouse.wheel(deltaX, deltaY);
```

Where deltax and y refer to pixels to move horizontally and vertically respectively. This could build flaky code however, as you are defining pixel values.

Or, if you wish to move to the very bottom, you can use the example here:
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4302#issuecomment-1882853669 (I wont take credit and post the code here)